# Dynamic Routing service not working , logs says 'Dynamic Routing servicesent 307 response to the client ihsserver13036 because client expired'

Tags: websphere-liberty

Currently, we are using Liberty 8.5.5.5 for our product,using Dynamic Routing feature 1.0.It's working pretty well before, but after may be 20 days or long, I am not able to access my web application through http server, after I restarted the http server, back to use.

I found that there are some warning messages in the console.log

```
Launching controller01 (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5/wlp-1.0.8.cl50520150305-2202) on IBM J9 VM, version pxa6470sr8fp10ifx-20150313_01 (SR8 FP10+IV70681) (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server controller01 has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0028A: Processing included configuration resource: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/controller01/collective-create-include.xml
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [collectiveMember-1.0, ssl-1.0, json-1.0, dynamicRouting-1.0, jsp-2.2, restConnector-1.0, adminCenter-1.0, servlet-3.0, jaxrs-1.1, jndi-1.0, collectiveController-1.0, distributedMap-1.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server controller01 is ready to run a smarter planet.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ifetest.cn.ibm.com:9080/ibm/api/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ifetest.cn.ibm.com:9080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ifetest.cn.ibm.com:9080/ibm/adminCenter/deploy-1.0/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ifetest.cn.ibm.com:9080/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://ifetest.cn.ibm.com:9080/adminCenter/
[WARNING ] CWWKV0008W: Dynamic Routing service sent 307 response to the client ihsserver13036 because client expired.
[WARNING ] CWWKV0008W: Dynamic Routing service sent 307 response to the client ihsserver13036 because client expired.
[WARNING ] CWWKV0008W: Dynamic Routing service sent 307 response to the client ihsserver13036 because client expired.
```

Can anyone help me understand this log?

Answer (score 1):

The CWWKV0008W message you are seeing in the log means that the communication between the web server plugin and the Liberty controller is taking longer than expected.

The plug-in keeps an HTTP GET request open to the controller. The controller delivers routing changes to the plug-in as a response to the open GET request. After a routing change has been delivered, the controller expects the next GET request from the plug-in to come within 15 seconds. If the plug-in sends that next GET request after more than 15 seconds, the controller will write the message you are seeing to the log, then ask the plug-in to re-initialize its connection.

This indicates some kind of network problem. If the message is intermittent it will not cause routing selection to fail. If the message is written continuously, you will have to debug network problems.

You can try debugging your problem to get more information about what is happening.

Add the xml element

`<TraceSpecification name="default" specification=":DEBUG"/>`

inside the

`<IntelligentManagement>`

stanza of your plugin-cfg.xml.
Information about what the plug-in is doing will be written to the file specified by the 'Name' attribute of the `<Log>` xml element in the plugin-cfg.xml. ( for example --- Name="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/logs/ihsserver/http_plugin.log").

You can also get information about the routing table that is used by the plug-in from the server-status command of the web server.
In httpd.conf, search for server-status. A few lines down, uncomment the line 'Allow from 127.0.0.1'. You can then browse to the server-status page of your web server, if your browser is running on the same host as the web server.

Using the two sets of information might help you to figure out what is causing the routing to fail.